alimentazione tramite pin usb
I would like to power a Raspberry Pi via the USB pins between PP1 and PP2. A guide said Don't bypass the RPi power fuse. what does it mean 

The Raspberry Pi usually includes a polyfuse or a similar component in its power circuitry. This fuse is designed to protect the Raspberry Pi from overcurrent situations. If the current exceeds a safe limit, the fuse will trip, cutting off the power to the board and preventing damage. Bypassing the fuse means connecting the power source directly to the USB pins, thereby circumventing the protection provided by the fuse. This can be risky because if there's a sudden surge in current or a short circuit, there's no protection to prevent damage to the Raspberry Pi.
